# Scala DSL: invocation that mimics English

Tags: scala, dsl

I'm very new to scala and this is a more of a question of curiosity.

Let's say I have a class

```
class Container()
{
    def add(item: Item) ...
}
```

I can invoke it like this: `container add item`.
I wonder what will it take to turn this invocation into English-like `add item to container`? It probably gonna be against the styleguides but as I said I'm just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I like a good challenge, I tried whether you can't get to where you want if you abuse almost every dangerous and/or experimental feature Scala has to offer, and it turns out it is possible:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import scala.language.dynamics
import scala.language.postfixOps
import scala.language.experimental.macros

import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context

case class Item(i: Int)
class Container { var item: Item = null; def add(i: Item) = item = i }

object to
object add extends Dynamic { def applyDynamic(item: String)(a: to.type) = new AddContainer}
class AddContainer extends Dynamic { def selectDynamic(container: String): Unit = macro addMacro }

/**
 * Don't try this at home: not a foolproof macro!
 */
def addMacro(c: Context)(container: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  val Literal(Constant(containerName: String)) = container
  val q"$_.applyDynamic($item)($_)" = c.prefix.tree
  val Literal(Constant(itemName: String)) = item
  q"${TermName(containerName)}.add(${TermName(itemName)})"
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.


scala> object Test {
     |   val item = Item(1)
     |   val container = new Container
     |   println(container.item)
     | 
     |   add item to container
     | 
     |   println(container.item)
     | }
defined object Test

scala> Test
null
Item(1)
```

Let's break this up into understandable parts.

You want to write `add item to container`, which gets parsed as `add.item(to).container`. The consequences for an implementation are:

- You need to enable postfixOps so you can use `container` as a postfix operator.
- `item` and `container` are both in method call position but we want them to refer to variables in the current scope. To overcome this we need to combine 2 features:

  - With [`Dynamic`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/Dynamic.html) we can turn `a.b(c)` into `a.applyDynamic("b")(c)` and `a.b` into `a.selectDynamic("b")`. So the method names get turned into strings which we can dynamically process.
  - Then we need a macro to turn these strings into identifiers referring to our variables. We extract the `String` literals from the syntax tree, turn them into `TermName`s and output a new syntax tree that looks like `container.add(item)`.

To keep it simple, this macro only works for the most trivial cases. It would probably take a lot more effort to get this to work reliably. And to make it very clear: this is just to answer the question of "what will it take". I doubt there's a usecase that would justify actually doing exactly this. However the techniques used here could probably be applied to some very advanced, but valid, usecase.

Answer (score 4):

Andrey has pointed out that this is not possible because of the ordering of methods and values. But you can fix this by being polite and adding "please".

```
please add item to container
```

Here is an implementation of `please`...

```
object please {
  case class Adder(item: Item) {
    def to(c: Container) =
      c.add(item)
  }

  def add(i: Item) = Adder(i)
}
```

If you don't like `please` then other options include `siri`, `alexa`,  `heyGoogle`, and `hal` :)

Comment: Obligatory reference to the INTERCAL reference manual: [10.4 PLEASE politesse checking](https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/intercal-man/s10.html#4).

Answer (score 2):

Looks impossible to me.

These kinds of Scala DSLs are essentially just chains of method calls without dots and parentheses:

```
v1.m1(v2).m2(v3)
```

written as

```
v1 m1 v2 m2 v3
```

with some values `v1, v2, ...` and methods `m1, m2, ...`.

Here you have

```
'add' value 'to' value
```

However you define `'add'` and `'to'`, it doesn't fit into the `value-method-value-method` pattern.

Comment: Right now I'm thinking of unary function `add(item: Item): PartialCollectionAddition` and then `to` function inside the `PartialCollectionAddition` that actually adds item to the collection.

Comment: @SimpleV if you are thinking about something like `def add(i: Int) = ???` and invoking it with `add 42`, it won't work: current REPL says *"error: ';' expected but integer literal found"*. The `a b` syntax collides with postfix method invocation `a.b`, but you cannot invoke `42` on `add`, because there is no value `add`, and there is no method `42`.